# Which folder should I put admin-related JS files?

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, javascript, security

I've written a few javascripts which are meant for the admin, but I'm not sure in which folder I should place these JS files. These scripts will be embeded in the pages in the Magento admin panel.

The folders in `/skin/adminhtml` are accessible by anyone and I don't think that is a good place for scripts meant for admin.

In which folder should I place my JS scripts which are meant for the admin? If not, how can I place the scripts in a folder which will only be accessible in the admin panel?

Comment: It should be in `skin/adminhtml` folder

Comment: app/design/adminhtml/your-theme/default/layout/local.xml

Comment: @PankajPareek Like I have mentioned, that folder is accessible to the public. :(

Comment: @Arjun isn't this the folder for layout.xml only?

Comment: frontend files must be in public accessible folder. As you will add files for backend so no one will know about your files. also you must have htaccess so that files list will not show on browser.

Comment: In root js folder. Sry by mistake is wrote for adding js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`skin/adminhtml` is the correct place. Yes, these files are publicly accessible, but if there is sensitive information in static JavaScript files, you are probably doing something wrong.

Try to move anything that should not be seen into PHTML templates. For example if you have JavaScript like this:

```
SecretService.prototype.init = function() {
  this.secretKey = 'abcdefg';
}
```

change it to

```
SecretService.prototype.init = function(key) {
  this.secretKey = key;
}
```

and move instantiation to a template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
new SecretService('abcdefg');
</script>
```

Then you also have the advantage to be able to use PHP and get such data from the configuration instead of hard coding it.